# OpenCV implementation of PSNR returns a value of 361 for two identical images

Tags: python, opencv

I was testing the PSNR implementation of OpenCV using python and I had a strange result.

I tried to calculate the PSNR between two identical images: the value should be an error because the MSE should be equal to zero. However the result was equal to 361! Can someone explain to me why did we get such a result?

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread("image1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("image1.png")
psnr = cv2.PSNR(img1,img2)
print(psnr)
```

Comment: 361 db is a huge number and probably the computer equivalent of infinity (maximum value) for its internally casted data type. If you convert to exponential format it is 10^36. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3119e3ea73010a6f810bb05aa36ac8d6

Comment: So instead of returning an error they return a big number ? Where can I find the implementation ?

Comment: That is my interpretation. I do not know where to look other than look in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of PSNR can be found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ecf5f106aeeb603cd83640a79357820fce25eaf/modules/core/src/norm.cpp#L1288).

The last two source lines are:

```cpp
double diff = std::sqrt(norm(_src1, _src2, NORM_L2SQR)/(_src1.total()*_src1.channels()));

return 20*log10(R/(diff+DBL_EPSILON));
```

A small value `DBL_EPSILON` is added to the denominator which prevents division by zero.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h> // For DBL_EPSILON
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int R = 255; // default value
    double diff = 0;
    std::cout << 20*log10(R/(diff + DBL_EPSILON)) << std::endl;
}
```

Above program in C++ prints value of `361.201`, which is the same as the value printed in Python.

Comment: That implementation is using an unnecessary `sqrt`... It could do without and use 10*log10 instead.